# Ubuntu Video Streaming

Tags: video, video-editor, video-streaming

my sisters theatre group needs a live stream for their new play. Someone will film the scene and we send it to a beamer via my laptop computer (running on Ubuntu Gnome 15.04). At some point the video fades to a white noise image or something like that as you know it from old TVs.
**However, is there a software running on Linux which provides live manipulating of video streams?**